# Como fazer um arquivo pdf gerado no Android aparecer como download?

Tags: android, pdf

Bem pessoal, estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo e eu gero um PDF no Android em tempo de execução. Acontece que o usuário não recebe nenhuma mensagem, nem nada, pra saber onde o arquivo se encontra. Gostaria de saber se tem como eu enviar esse arquivo para o download manager do Android, existe essa possibilidade? Se não, qual a melhor forma de mostrar pro usuário onde o arquivo está sendo escrito? (Está sendo escrito na pasta do próprio aplicativo)

Comment: Como não sabemos como você está a fazer isso e difícil responder.

Comment: Jaja vou postar o código @ramaral, estou no celular. Mas assim. De uma forma mais simples de ser explicada: Como pegar um arquivo que já está salvo no dispositivo e fazer aparece-lo no como se estivesse sendo feito seu download?

Comment: Se o *pdf* está ser gerado num serviço, crie uma notificação. Se está a ser gerado na aplicação que o usuário está a utilizar, crie um *dialog* a informar onde ele foi gravado.

Comment: Vou testar estas soluções então, valeu!

Comment: @JoãoNeto Da uma olhada no código do autor dessa pergunta: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908193/how-to-access-downloads-folder-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi da seguinte forma:

Criei um download manager e adicionei o arquivo. Fazendo isso ele adiciona a pasta de downlaods e a lista de downloads, e também mostra uma notificação.

```
File arquivo = getFile(fileName); // Meu método para pegar o arquivo.
DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
dm.addCompletedDownload(fileName, "Portal do Aluno Ufac: "+fileName, true, "application/pdf", arquivo.getAbsolutePath(), arquivo.length(), true);
```